# creating an images gallery

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I m trying to create an image gallery where the images are stored in resource bundle. I'm storing my images in  NSMutable array what i want is an image gallery ....but the output    is pretty different from wat i expected.the below code works perfectly fine.to be more specific  cud u guys help me out below is the code...

[image]

```
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo1.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo2.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo3.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo4.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo5.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo6.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo7.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo8.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo9.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo10.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo11.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo12.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo13.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo14.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo15.png"]];
[_images  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo16.png"]];

NSLog(@"ha ha ha:%d",_images.count);



UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
int row=0;
int coloumn=0;
for (int i=0; i< _images.count; i++)
{
    UIImage *thumb=[_images objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(coloumn*100+24, row*80+30, 64, 64);
    [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag=i;
    [view addSubview:button];
    if (coloumn==2) {
        coloumn==0;
        row++;
    }else {
        coloumn++;
    }

}

[view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (row+1)*80+10)];
self.view=view;
[view release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the three20 library

[iPhone SDK: Creating a Photo Gallery With Three20](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-photo-gallery-three20/)

[image]

**Edited:**

**Your code are excellent except on wrong statement :**

```
coloumn==0;
```

that's the reason your colomn always point to the 2nd coloumn.

So change it to **coloumn = 0;**

Comment: i tried using three20...it doesnt integrate with tabbar applications..and is pretty complicated

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is here:

```
if (coloumn==2) {
    coloumn==0;   //-- ERROR!
    row++;
```

this should be:

```
    coloumn=0;   //-- correct!
```

using == instead of =

Comment: @sergio : No offence dude , After seeing my updated answer which i updated 6 min ago (by now), you just posted your answer by adding some text, this is not good, we need to maintain and follow some rules implicitly.

Comment: @Jhaliya: I really don't understand how you can say that... no offence, but stay assured that it is not true.

Comment: @ sergio :no offence, let's not get into that and we should stick to good practice.

Comment: @Jhaliya: no offence, but seriously, you should know. it takes time from when you enter a page and start reading a question to when you finish editing your answer. In the meanwhile, *edited* questions are not notified, only new questions are (and even those, with a couple of minutes of delay). This is what happened. Anyway, once again: rest assured that I follow all the rules of good practice.

Comment: @sergio :you are absolutely right with your words, it take time and i think we should keep answering and thanks for healthy conversation.

Answer (score 0):

This works very well but you would have to make a few adjustments to the code when you change the size. Copy and paste it in your `Viewdidload`; make sure you have a `UIScrollview` with IB already setup with a link name `scrollView`.

```
int row    = 0;
int colomn = 0;
int width  = 79;
int height = 79;
int offset = 1;
// int diff   = width * 0.5;
CGRect rect;

for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {

    if(i == 0){

        colomn = 0;

    }else{

        colomn += width + offset;

    };

    if(colomn >= ((int)scrollView.frame.size.width) - width){

        colomn = 0;
        row += height + offset;

    }

       rect =  CGRectMake(colomn, row, width, height);


    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [scrollView addSubview:view];

}

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, row+height)];
```

Comment: A better solution is to model the grid based on the view constraints, so that the application can adjust to changes, allow paging beyond the scrollview, and manipulate the grid objects themselves rather than hardcoding positions and setting them in the view.  Once these images are set in the scrollview you cant respond to events without repeating all the same logic to do hit testing, and you have no object identity for the photos.